# Arrange calculated columns immediately after source columns when using dplyr column-wise operations

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to arrange calculated columns immediately after source columns when using dplyr column-wise operations

```
library(dplyr)
```

Example data

```
df <- tibble(
  id         = c(1, 2, 2),
  id_row     = c(1, 1, 2),
  name_first = c("John", "Jane", "Jane"),
  city       = c("NY", "DAL", "HOU"),
  x          = c(0, 1, 0)
)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id id_row name_first city      x
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <dbl>
1     1      1 John       NY        0
2     2      1 Jane       DAL       1
3     2      2 Jane       HOU       0
```

Within ID, the values of name_first and city should be constant. The values for id_row and x need not be constant. I want to test for and inspect differing values of name_first and city within-id.

One convenient way to do this is with `mutate()` and `across()`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols  = c(name_first, city),
      .fns   = ~ length(unique(.x)) == 1,
      .names = "{col}_all_match"
    )
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   id [2]
     id id_row name_first city      x name_first_all_match city_all_match
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <lgl>                <lgl>         
1     1      1 John       NY        0 TRUE                 TRUE          
2     2      1 Jane       DAL       1 TRUE                 FALSE         
3     2      2 Jane       HOU       0 TRUE                 FALSE
```

The issue is that the "all_match" (calculated) columns are added to the far right of the data frame rather than immediately after their source column. This makes it difficult to visually inspect differing values for the columns of interest.

Of course, in this small data frame, we could easily rearrange the columns using `select()`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols  = c(name_first, city),
      .fns   = ~ length(unique(.x)) == 1,
      .names = "{col}_all_match"
    )
  ) %>% 
  select(id, id_row, starts_with("name_first"), starts_with("city"), x)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   id [2]
     id id_row name_first name_first_all_match city  city_all_match     x
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <lgl>                <chr> <lgl>          <dbl>
1     1      1 John       TRUE                 NY    TRUE               0
2     2      1 Jane       TRUE                 DAL   FALSE              1
3     2      2 Jane       TRUE                 HOU   FALSE              0
```

The issue with that approach is that it quickly becomes pretty cumbersome with more columns. A more tractable approach would be to sort the names alphabetically...

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols  = c(name_first, city),
      .fns   = ~ length(unique(.x)) == 1,
      .names = "{col}_all_match"
    )
  ) %>% 
  select(sort(names(.)))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   id [2]
  city  city_all_match    id id_row name_first name_first_all_match     x
  <chr> <lgl>          <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <lgl>                <dbl>
1 NY    TRUE               1      1 John       TRUE                     0
2 DAL   FALSE              2      1 Jane       TRUE                     1
3 HOU   FALSE              2      2 Jane       TRUE                     0
```

...but in my situation I need to preserve the original column order. I'd also prefer to stick with Tidyverse solutions if possible.

Any ideas are appreciated!

[Also posted on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/arrange-calculated-columns-immediately-after-source-columns-when-using-dplyr-column-wise-operations/101726)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you (obviously) know which columns you want to mutate, you can leverage that ahead of time to create a column order:

```
cols <- c("name_first", "city")
col_order <- unlist(lapply(names(df), function(x) if (x %in% cols) c(x, paste0(x, "_all_match")) else x))

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols  = cols,
      .fns   = ~ length(unique(.x)) == 1,
      .names = "{col}_all_match"
    )
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(col_order)
```

**Output**

```
     id id_row name_first name_first_all_match city  city_all_match     x
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <lgl>                <chr> <lgl>          <dbl>
1     1      1 John       TRUE                 NY    TRUE               0
2     2      1 Jane       TRUE                 DAL   FALSE              1
3     2      2 Jane       TRUE                 HOU   FALSE              0
```

---

This is an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2047) that's been raised before in `mutate` and there exists an experimental `.after` and `.before` that works with a single variable. When these arguments are used with `across`, all newly created variables will be positioned together before or after the variable specified, which is not what you want.

Though I think it would be helpful to be able to insert a column after its source, there isn't really tidyverse functionality for this.

Comment: Hi @LMc, thank you for the response. Unfortunately, that doesn't give the result I'm looking for. That puts "name_first_all_match" AND "city_all_match" behind city. I'm trying to put name_first_all_match behind name_first and city_all_match behind city.

Comment: @BradCannell I've updated my answer. I think this is an interesting functionality that isn't really present in the tidyverse.

Comment: Thank you, @LMc! It doesn't feel like the most satisfying solution, but it definitely gets the job done.